# NestJs ParseEnumPipe can't be resolve

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am using the NestJs framework (love it by the way) and I want to check the incoming data so it conforms with an Enum in Typscript. So I have the following:

```
enum ProductAction {
  PURCHASE = 'PURCHASE',
}

@Patch('products/:uuid')
async patchProducts(
    @Param('uuid', ParseUUIDPipe) uuid: string,
    @Body('action', ParseEnumPipe) action: ProductAction,
  ) {

    switch(action) {

    ... code 
  }
```

The weird thing is that when I run this code, the first pipe gets compiled

```
2022-07-21 16:53:51 [error] [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ParseEnumPipe (?, Object). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the FriendsModule context.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `@Body('action', new ParseEnumPipe(ProductAction)) action: ProductAction` because enums aren't directly reflected for Nest to read the metadata of, and because Nest is otherwise trying to figure out how to inject `Object` when it really should be injecting the enum.

Comment: I guess we could improve the docs on that pipe